# How do I do this "If n is 3, return `1+..1+2+..1+2+3+..`"

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, while-loop

Define a function named `nested_increasing_additions(n)` which receives one positive integer `(n)` and **returns a string** as illustrated in the following examples:

If `n` is `3`, the function should return the string:
`1+..1+2+..1+2+3+..`

If `n` is `5`, the function should return the string:
`1+..1+2+..1+2+3+..1+2+3+4+..1+2+3+4+5..+`

What I think is, I can make `n` to a list `[1,2,3]` and use while loop or for loop to repeat `n` times. For the first loop it returns `1+..`, for the second loop it returns `1+2..` somehow (which i don't know) it stops at `2` which is the same as the repeating time.

I don't know if I'm thinking it right. Need some help and explanations! Thank you!

Comment: Could you show your code?

Comment: why does your first string end with `..` but the second one doesn't?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build the complete string step by step, and remember at each step what you have added last:

```
def nested_increasing_additions(n):
    complete_string = ""
    add_string = ""
    for i in range(1,n+1):
        add_string += str(i) + "+"
        complete_string += add_string + ".."
    return complete_string

print(nested_increasing_additions(1))
print(nested_increasing_additions(3))
print(nested_increasing_additions(5))
```

The output with python3 is:

```
1+..
1+..1+2+..1+2+3+..
1+..1+2+..1+2+3+..1+2+3+4+..1+2+3+4+5+..
```

Answer (score 4):

Consecutive evaluations of these strings results in a sequence of *tetrahedral numbers*.  For example, for input 5, the output evaluates to 35.  This is the number of spheres you would need to build a tetrahedron of side length 5.

[image: tetrahedron]

To see how it relates to the sum in the question, note that the discrete "volume" of the tetrahedron would be equal to the sum of the triangle "slices" from top to bottom.

```
35 = 1 + 3 + 6 + 10 + 15
   = 1 + (1+2) + (1+2+3) + (1+2+3+4) + (1+2+3+4+5)
```

By a similar argument, the triangular numbers are made up of slices of consecutive integers.

---

Please excuse the maths, it was difficult (but not impossible) to adapt a closed-form solution into the desired output format.

```
def tetrahedral(n): 
    return n*(n+1)*(n+2)//6


def string_generator(n):
    x = tetrahedral(n)
    n = N = 1
    while x > 0:
        while n <= N:
            yield str(n) + '+'
            n += 1
        x -= N*(N+1)//2
        n = 1
        N += 1
        yield '..'


def nested_increasing_additions(n):
    return ''.join(string_generator(n))
```

Comment: "the function should return the *string*" emphasis mine

Comment: A whole new level of getting nerd-sniped, congratulations!

Answer (score 0):

```
def nested_increasing_additions(n):
    l=['']
    for i in range(1, n+1):
        l.append(l[-1]+str(i)+'+')
    return '..'.join(l[1:])
```

This returns a string without the `..` at the end.  If you want that, just do `return '..'.join(l[1:]) + '..'`

Answer (score 0):

you can use something like this.

```
def nested_increasing_additions(n):
    string = ""
    for i in range(1,n+1): #1
        for j in range(1,i+1): #2
            string += str(j)+"+" #4
        string += ".." #5
    print(string)
```

here is a printout of nested_increasing_additions(4)
1+..1+2+..1+2+3+..1+2+3+4+..
i think it's self explanatory, nothing complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you did want the `".."` at the end of each returned string and that recursion is OK, here's a solution:

```
def nested_increasing_additions(n):
    if n == 1:
        return "1+.."
    else:
        return nested_increasing_additions(n-1) + '%s+..' % '+'.join(str(i) for i in range(1, n+1))

print(nested_increasing_additions(3))
print(nested_increasing_additions(5))
type(nested_increasing_additions(1))
```

**Prints**:

```
1+..1+2+..1+2+3+..
1+..1+2+..1+2+3+..1+2+3+4+..1+2+3+4+5+..
<type 'str'>
```

**Explanation**:

- The first return and if (true) block ends the recursive call when the passed in argument value reaches 1 via subtraction from the other half.
- The second half (else block) calls the next iteration with `n` subtracted by 1 and the string build of the current iteration (if `n!=1`).
- The complicated looking code `'%s+..' % '+'.join(str(i) for i in range(1, n+1))` is just concatenation of a list of numbers generated by the `range` function, turned into strings and `"+.."`

  - `range(1, n+1)` returns a list of integers starting with 1 until `n+1` so `range(1,3)` yields `[1,2]`. This is passed to join which places a `+` between each number.

Answer (score 0):

How's this:

```
def nested_increasing_additions(n):

    string = ""
    new_string = ""
    dot = ".."

    for i in range(1, n+1):
        new_string+=('{}+'.format(i))
        string = string+new_string+dot
        print(string)

    return (string)
```

Output:

```
nested_increasing_additions(3)    

'1+..1+2+..1+2+3+..'
```